# How can I increase the amount of frames, but replicate the flip fluids simulation exactly?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I made flip fluids simulation where an object falls into water and makes an interesting looking splash. The simulation is 30 frames long. The objects motion is controlled by key frames one of which is on frame 1 and the other of which is on frame 30. The fps is set to 60 in both blender settings and flip fluids settings. To increase the amount of frames and make it slow motion, I set the animation to 450 frames, moved the second key frame of the falling object to frame 450, and changed the fps to 900 in both blender settings and flip fluids settings. From what I understand, that should produce the exact same mesh in both simulations. The same mesh on frame 30 in the first simulation and on frame 450 in the second simulation. However, the second simulation does not appear the same and instead it is very uneventful since it barely produces any splash at all. So how can I increase the amount of frames, but replicate the simulation exactly?